# LibGDX - Distorted rendered 3d model

Tags: libgdx, render, compatibility, game-engine

I have a 3d model exported from 3ds Max and converted to g3db format.
The rendered model looks different on two different phones. 
When i run the app on **Micromax Unite 2**, the rendered view is sharp and exact.
But for **Nexus 5 or Emulator** it is distorted..

Snapshot of Nexus 5 and Micromax Unite 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fyy7j.jpg

I have followed and implemented the code from: http://xoppa.github.io/blog/interacting-with-3d-objects/

**MyCode**

**AndroidLauncher.java**

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    config.useGLSurfaceView20API18 = true;
    config.numSamples = 4;

    initialize(new Viewer3D);
} }
```

**Viewer3d.java**

```
@Override
public void create () {
    stage = new Stage();
    font = new BitmapFont();
    label = new Label(" ", new Label.LabelStyle(font, Color.WHITE));

    stage.addActor(label);
    stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    modelBatch = new ModelBatch();
    environment = new Environment();
    environment.set(new ColorAttribute(ColorAttribute.AmbientLight, 0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1f));
    environment.add(new DirectionalLight().set(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 100,1000,300));

    cam = new PerspectiveCamera(67, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    cam.position.set((float) (maxX/2f+radius * Math.sin(finalAngle)), finalY, (float) (maxZ/2f+radius * Math.cos(finalAngle)));
    cam.lookAt(centerX, 1500, centerY);
    cam.up.set(Vector3.Y);
    cam.near = 1;
    cam.far = 7000;
    cam.update();

    camController = new CameraInputController(cam);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputMultiplexer(this, camController));

    Arrays.fill(usedIndexes, false);

    assets = new AssetManager();
    assets.load("models" + "/final.g3db", Model.class);//
    loading = true;
}

@Override
public void render () {
    if (loading && assets.update()) 
        doneLoading();

    camController.update();

    Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    modelBatch.begin(cam);
    visibleCount = 0;
    for (final GameObject instance : instances) {
        if (isVisible(cam, instance)) {
            modelBatch.render(instance, environment);
            visibleCount++;
        }
    }
    if (Sky != null)
        modelBatch.render(Sky);
    modelBatch.end();
    stage.draw();
}

/* updaing my camera position such that it moves in a circle in XZ-plane */
private void updateCamera() {
    float x = (float) (centerX + radius * Math.sin(finalAngle));
    float z = (float) (centerY + radius * Math.cos(finalAngle));
    // Constrained camera posX > 0 posZ > 0
    cam.position.set(x < 0 ? 0 : x , 3000, z < 0 ? 0 : z);

    cam.lookAt(centerX, 1500, centerY);
    cam.up.set(Vector3.Y);
    cam.update();
    camController = new CameraInputController(cam);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputMultiplexer(this, camController));
}
```

I have tried:
1. `config.numSamples = 8;`
2. `config.immersiveMode = true`
But nothing worked ! :(
Kindly help.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Xoppa Kindly, review my edited question. I have clarified the problem and added the code. I am very stressed.

Comment: Looks like your model is way too big. Use meaningful units, e.g. meters. Your cam.far should not be 7000 times your cam.near, keep it as low as possible (in your scene it should be around 10 or 20 meters).

Comment: @Xoppa i have used feet as unit in 3ds max, which is scaled to (=12* 25.4*feet) size in libgdx. Is there a way to use feet-inches as unit in Libgdx

Comment: @Xoppa You saved my life dude. near plane was the actual culprit.  It worked !!